# Providing DNS for Kubernetes services with bare metal load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, metallb, external-dns

I'm trying to use [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) with a bare metal load balancer. I tried using [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) as the kubernetes load balancer, but the IP address assigned in the A record is the internal IP address of the load balancer, rather than than the public IP address of the load balancer. According the to the external-dns docs, if `status.loadBalancer` is empty (which it will always be), external-dns would not work as expected even though I have set the external IP for the service.

Comment: what k8s version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.14.7

Comment: would you like to create records based on Ingresses, Services or any other resource types?

Answer (score 0):

`external-dns` needs to become aware of the IP address of the loadbalancer. If the `status.loadbalancer` field is empty, one way how to make `external-dns` aware of the correct IP is to use the annotation `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/target: "<metalLB-vip>"`